# How to provoke a broken pipe

Tags: python, pipe, socket, mpd

I try to debug a python script that interfaces [MPD](http://www.musicpd.org/) using [python-mpd2](https://github.com/Mic92/python-mpd2).

When the script tries to perform an action after being idle for a couple of hours, it terminates with an exception (`BrokenPipeError` in Python 3, `socket.pipe` in Python 2 - `[Errno 32] Broken pipe` in both cases).

The fact that the broken pipe only appears after hours of idle time makes debugging extremely slow.

Is there a way to provoke the same behavior - a broken pipe to mpd - manually?

Comment: That's quite typical behavior, actually; connection gets broken. Why can't you just catch the exception and reconnect?

Comment: It might be typical but it's not that easy :) you can read more on my efforts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718208/catch-broken-pipe-in-python-2-and-python-3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463087/raise-exception-in-python-2-x-and-3-x and https://github.com/Mic92/python-mpd2/issues/64. However, I am quite close to a solution. But - as I point out in my question - testing is quite time consuming and I am looking for a way to speed up this process.

Comment: Then you might try to disconnect the network - would it work for you?

Comment: Stop the MPD service / daemon (forcibly if necessary)?

Comment: @TNW well, the mpd server runs on localhost but sometimes on a remote pc (a raspberry pi) so disconnecting the network probably wouldn't work.

Comment: @EightBitTony This would be a possibility. But not knowing much about pipes and sockets I don't know if a terminated service appears to be the same as a broken pipe for the python script. Also I wondered if there was a more gentle way... but if there is none...

Comment: @Marcel not sure either, give it a shot with a graceful stop of the daemon and see how the pipe behaves, if that doesn't work, just kill -9 the daemon, as long as it's not writing to any files, kill -9 shouldn't be too harsh on it ;)

Answer (score 2):

according to `man 7 signal`

> SIGPIPE      13       Term    Broken pipe: write to pipe with no
>                                       readers

so the answer should be

```
kill -13 1234
```

(1234 being your PID)

(broken pipe are bad luck ? )

Comment: Thank you for your answer! One question remaining: with PID do you mean the PID of the main process (in my case the mpd service) or does the pipe have it's own PID)?

Comment: try main process first.

Comment: I just tried it out. with `kill -13 <mpd PIP>` there is no `BrokenPipeError` that is thrown... :(